# symfony 4 session timeout

Tags: symfony, session

I am currently struggling with symfony sessions as described here https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html.
In my project I have the following controller method:

```
/**
 * @Route("/update", name="update")
 */
public getUserProfile(ProfileDTO $profileDTO, SessionInterface $session) : Response {
    $token = $session->get('token');
    $userId = $this->sessionRepository->lookUp($token);
    $this->userService->update($userId, $profileDTO);
}
```

So, basically, when the user logs in, I want to store a unique token for the session in the sessionvariable as well as in the database. Then, when he wants to update his profile, I want to read his token from the sessionvariable.
But what will happen if the session timeouts (e.g. if the user tries to update his profile a week after having logged in the last time)? Will the call $session->get('token') just return null? I could not find this information in the documentation (https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html)

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

yes, this will return null.
If you have the default session settings, your session will end when you close and restart your browser, this way you can verify my answer easily :)